# Error running : apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, fonts

I am attempting to install the MS Core fonts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and am running into the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: cabextract but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` doesn't return anything and I can't find a package in apt-get called `cabextract`.

From everything I've Googled, installing the MS Core fonts is relatively straightforward, so I'm a tad lost.  How can I resolve this issue and install the core fonts?

**Edit:**

Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted multiverse
```

Comment: What this command returns? `apt-mark showhold `

Comment: @KasiyA it doesn't return anything.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends build-dep ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and reply the changes.

Comment: Oh, that did something.  Returned an error though.  `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: see [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/283843)

Comment: or try `sudo apt-get install aptitude` then `sudo aptitude install cabextract` then try to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. if doesn't solve try `aptitude why-not cabextract` and post the output of that in body of your question

Comment: When I tried to install `cabextract` I got this error: `No candidate version found for cabextract`.  When I ran `aptitude why-not cabextract` it returned `Unable to find a reason to remove cabextract.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cabextract` is in the `universe` repository, if you update your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

apt will install cabextract to meet the dependencies of the partially installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer. If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Still getting the error.  The error text is the exact same.  (I tried putting it in the comment, but it was just unreadable)