# Unable to install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: fonts

While trying to install MSCOREFONTS the following error occured:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version (3.6).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fonts-lohit-mlym : Breaks: ttf-malayalam-fonts (<= 1:0.5.12) but 1:0.5.11ubuntu1 is to be installed
 fonts-mlym : Breaks: ttf-malayalam-fonts (< 2:1.0) but 1:0.5.11ubuntu1 is to be installed
 fonts-samyak-mlym : Breaks: ttf-malayalam-fonts (< 2:1.0) but 1:0.5.11ubuntu1 is to be installed
 fonts-smc : Breaks: ttf-malayalam-fonts (< 2:1.0) but 1:0.5.11ubuntu1 is to be installed
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: cabextract
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: `ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version (3.6).`, so there is no installation needed. If you refer to the `unmet dependencies` messages, did you try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as suggested?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571842/error-running-apt-get-install-ttf-mscorefonts-installer): I hope this helps.

Comment: Please execute the suggested command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and append the results of that operation to your question.